# Profile text isn't formatted properly in profile preview

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, formatting, user-card

In my profile text I have some links formatted as a list:

[image]

But when I look at a question or an answer of mine, the hover preview doesn't show the links below each other:

[image]

As you can see, the last two links are set directly behind the third link. Why? Is there a possibility that the links are set correctly below each other (even if the last one would be hidden because of the length of the preview)? I thought SO would automatically do this when I use a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user card only displays up to a certain number of characters as a summary of your profile text. Then below that, it pulls any links that didn't appear in the summary and displays those side by side. It's cutting off your summary after the second link because the third would put you past the character limit, and then displaying your other three links in an alternate format. There is no way to make all five of those links as written appear below each other.

Comment: Ah, so if they wouldn't be links, it wouldn't show them like this?

Comment: If they weren't links they wouldn't all be displayed at the bottom like that. Depending on how many characters you had left in your summary, parts of plain text could end up at the bottom to meet the rest of your character count, but the summary only displays a link in it if the entire link can be included.